# Eclipse Android remove titlebar

Tags: java, android, eclipse, titlebar

I am trying below code to remove title bar:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

But the title bar still appears.

I also tried `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"` but that crashs the app

Thanks for help!

Comment: Above code should work fine. You have some other issue. Better to provide more information

Comment: Check your Activity extends whose Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put one more line of code below your `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);`

So here goes the complete code for `onCreate` till `setContentView` :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
-------
-------
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**Into `onCreate()` add:**

`this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)`;

Comment: Thanks, i tried that but its still not working. I get the following in my console:
[2014-12-28 20:11:05 - Elevel] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2014-12-28 20:11:05 - Elevel] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-12-28 20:11:05 - Elevel] Launch canceled!

Comment: does the application works then crashes or it doesn't work at all?

Comment: It doesnt launch anymore

Comment: add the android:installLocation attribute to your application's manifest file, with the value "preferExternal".

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.andrewsmith.android.darkness"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"

Comment: The app is launching now but it still crashs. I took a screenshot of the LogCat: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WMKyw.png

Comment: try to set feature before super

Comment: if that didn't work use: getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);   //another alternative is leverage AsyncTask for dialogs search for it if non of the prev method worked !!

Comment: Well at least the app is launching now but the title bar is still there. I put the requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); before super and added this to my themestyle: <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
       <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>